# How to skip every 3rd element from the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to write a simple logic. Based on this logic I should implement my actual logic in project.

so far I have tried the below code.

```
int[] num = new int[11];

for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    num[2 * (i - 1) + 1] = i;
}

foreach (var item in num)
{
    Console.Write(item + " ");
}
```

The output is - 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0

But I want the output as in this 0 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 7 8 9 0 format.

What should be write in this code - `num[2 * (i - 1) + 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the return you want, try this:

```
var num = new int[12];
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    num[i + ((i - 1) / 3)] = i;
}
```

This yields: `0 1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 7 8 9`.

The logic behind it is that you need to add an extra 1 to the calculated index for every set of 3. The `- 1` is to shift the set-of-three to the required position.

### Update

To remove the first 0 you have to subtract 1 from the calculated index.

```
var num = new int[11];
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    num[i - 1 + ((i - 1) / 3)] = i;
}
```

This yields: `1 2 3 0 4 5 6 0 7 8 9`

Comment: The array size should be 12 I guess otherwise it will through index out of range exception var num = new int[12];

Comment: Maarten..If I want to remove the first zero what should be the logic

Comment: Correct. I copied the 11 from your sample.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow how skipping every 3rd element is going to yield the result you mentioned. But you need to figure out a way to identify each "3rd element" by looking at the index; this is commonly done using the MOD operator (`%` for C#, check the internet for "modulo operation") and then checking the result, `index % 2 == 0` would be `true` for every even value of `index` or "every 2nd value" if the index values are continouous.

The rest should be easy to figure out I guess.

Comment: I need to store in the array like num[2 * (i - 1) + 1] this format

Answer (score 0):

```
        int[] num = new int[11];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {

            if (i%4 != 0)
            {
                num[i] = i - j;
            }
            else
            {
                j= j + 1;
            }

        }

        foreach (var item in num)
        {
            Console.Write(item + " ");
        }
        Console.Read();
```